# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm getting the following error randomly. The code runs fine and all of a sudden I see this error. The code is written using typescript and running using pm2.
Node version: 10.16.3
Npm version: 6.9.0

```
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00:  1: 0x8fa0c0 node::Abort() [node /var/BCS/server/server.ts]
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00:  2: 0x8fa10c  [node /var/BCS/server/server.ts]
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00:  3: 0xb0026e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /var/BCS/server/server.ts]
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00:  4: 0xb004a4 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node /var/BCS/server/server.ts]
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00:  5: 0xef49b2  [node /var/BCS/server/server.ts]
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00:  6: 0xf041cf v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node /var/BCS/server/server.ts]
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00:  7: 0xed3d7b v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node /var/BCS/server/server.ts]
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00:  8: 0x101d603 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node /var/BCS/server/server.ts]
2019-10-03 23:05 +00:00:  9: 0xbd4c29 v8::internal::Builtin_JsonParse(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node /var/BCS/server/server.ts]
10: 0x1a9c8b1dbf7d
```

Need help as this is happening on a production env.

Comment: When I had this issue ,I had to increase my physical ram from 2GB to 4GB.Rest you can try this -https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit